# Document scanner on PC like with mobile apps

Tags: image-manipulation, scanner

I'm impressed with the abilities of document scanner apps for mobile devices. I've tried a few and they do a very similar thing very well: Take a camera picture/photo of a paper document, detect it's edges to assist the user with cropping, crop and correct perspective distortion, remove noise and background, recognize text - OCR, export to PDF.

I'm surprised I couldn't find any such advanced tooling for a desktop/laptop PC. Indeed there are plenty of articles about OpenCV, Imagemagic, Tesseract... and how to achieve particular tricks. I could do that, I could use GIMP to that effect, I guess, but I'm looking for a tool that will be efficient in every day digitization of shopping bills for instance. My laptop has a camera. I'd like it to do the same job as the mobile device. No need for bulky scanner. [Snap, fix](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/), OCR, store.

Oh, and I'm looking for a FOSS solution primarily.

Comment: your question is not about linux ... it belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @jsotola, let's move it, I've joined that community now